# Capturing a user's "enter" keystroke in C

Tags: c

I'm starting to learn C now and i'm trying to figure out how I would go about capturing when the user hits "enter."  I'm looking particularly at the scanf and getc functions but I'm not quite sure how to go about it.  When the user hits enter I want to perform some operations while waiting/watching for him to hit enter again...  Is "enter" a new line character coming in from the console?  Any advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: If you are getting some input from the user, example `scanf()` its blocking. So after the user types the input and presses enter the PC automatically goes to the next line of the program. You can input your code there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the ascii value using fgetc().

```
while(condition) {
    int c = fgetc(stdin);

    if (c==10) {//Enter key is pressed
    //your action
    }
}
```

Comment: While this is a good way, this will not work if the application needs the user to enter some input.

Comment: @noMAD I get your point. However, It's OP's job to explain under what scenario he needs this to work. Otherwise, I expect OP to modify this according to his need.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need the input when user presses enter as input you can use `scanf` or `getchar`. Here is an example from [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/getchar/)

```
/* getchar example : typewriter */
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
  char c;
  puts ("Enter text. Include a dot ('.') in a sentence to exit:");
  do {
    c=getchar();
    putchar (c);
  } while (c != '.');
  return 0;
}
```

This code prints what you entered to stdin (terminal window).

But if you do not want the input ( i know it's really unnecessary and complicated for a new learner) you should use an event handler.

Answer (score 1):

```
printf("Hit RETURN to exit"\n");
fflush(stdout);
(void)getchar();
```

Ref: [comp.lang.c FAQ list · Question 19.4b](http://c-faq.com/osdep/waitforkey.html)

Answer (score 0):

The C language is platform-independent and does not come with any keyboard interaction on its own. As you are writing a console program, it is the console that processes the keyboard input, then passes it to your program as a standard input. The console input/output is usually buffered, so you are not able to react to a single keypress, as the console only sends the input to the program after each line.

However! If you do not demand your console application to be platform-independent, there is a non-standard library `<conio.h>` in some Windows compilers that has a function called `getche();`, which does exactly what you want - wait for a single keypress from the console, returning the `char` that was pressed.